# Quick View is not working

Tags: jquery, magento

I am working on magento site.

My quick view is not working

here is link

192.232.214.244/suitnsave/

when i click on quick view. it redirects to another page. it supposed to be open fancy box.

Any idea.

Thanks

Comment: thats becoz its a url link with href attribute

Comment: Open your JavaScript console and make sure it doesn't clear upon navigation.  You should see the error that is preventing the `onClick` handler from interrupting navigation.

Comment: I have voted up for **super cool** because he/ she checked the link and then answered correctly. If you want to implement quick view, there are many free extensions available on magento connect, which will save your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to init fancybox. Something like `$(.quick_view > a").fancybox();`
2. You load like 4time the jQuery. So the jQuery with the fancybox in it gets overwritten. You can test it with `jQuery.fancybox`. Right now it returns `undefined`. That means the fancybox-plugin is not loaded in that current jQuery.

Remove the multible jQuerys and make sure you get the fancybox init right and you should be fine.